# How to delete content in sparse files?

Tags: c, mmap, sparse-file

I'm writing a program, which write some contents in a sparse file.
Say, I create the file by

```
fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644);
assert(fd != -1);
int s = ftruncate(fd, len);
```

`len` is very large, but the actual content may only takes several kbs.

Then I do memory mapped IO on this file. How do I ensure contents are deleted from this file, so that temporary stuff is not stored, and the actual storage is still "sparse"?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but perhaps you want to map with `MAP_PRIVATE`? This ensures that your changes are only made in memory, and never written back to the file itself, which stays unmodified.

Answer (score -2):

This question is beyond the scope of the C language. The C Standard does not have a notion of sparse files, nor even a notion of POSIX file handles.

Answers are OS specific. For linux, you may find a solution here: [What are functions to manipulate sparse files under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366378/205584) and [Detailed sparse file information on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/detailed-sparse-file-information-on-linux).